# Using a table like an object in Excel

Tags: excel, object, vba

I created a table in Excel, for example:

```
    
           A            B
    1    Fruit       Price ($)
    2    Apple          5
    3    Banana         3
    4    Orange         4
    5    Lemon          2
    6    Pineapple      4
```

The name for this table is Fruits. How can I use this table like a obejct in VBA code?

For example use in a Match function:

```
result = WorksheetFunction.Match("Banana", Table("Fruits").Column("Fruit"), 0)
```

And the result is 2.

---

Problem solved - One observation, it is better use `Application.Match` instead of `WorksheetFunction.Match`. The `WorksheetFunction.Match` returns `#Value!`, when the value is not found. Different than `Application.Match` that returns `#N/A`.

Comment: do you want the answer to be 2 because it's the 2nd item, or because the price is 2?

Comment: The answer is 2, because it is the 2nd item, was just coincidence the same price. I will change this, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a special construction of the range reference to appropriate column within your Table. It will be the best if I present it just improving your code:

```
result = WorksheetFunction.Match("Banana", Range("Fruits[Fruit]"), 0)
```

assuming that `Fruits` is a range name for the table. As a result `result = 2`

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked very well, it was exactly I needed!

Comment: This will return `Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class` when a match is not found. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895517/method-range-of-object-global-failed-in-excel-macro/21895895#21895895

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, tables are called ListObjects. ListObjects have ListRows and ListColumns. All of these (plus headers, totals, etc.) have a DataBodyRange property that returns a Range object.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Banana",Sheet1.ListObjects("Fruits").ListColumns("Fruit").DataBodyRange,False)
```

Comment: Hi Kusleika,
I tried your answer, but didn't work. The result was #VALUE!
I don't know what is wrong.
Well, thank you in the same way.