# method range of object _global failed in excel macro

Tags: vba

This is my code for finding a value in excel.if `Paint Shop` is not found then it will get the `method range of object _global failed`. I'm new to excel macro and can any body help me to solve this?

```
If WorksheetFunction.Match("Paint Shop", Range(col & x, col & y), 0) Then
   paint = WorksheetFunction.Match("Paint Shop", Range(col & x, col & y), 0)
Else
   paint = 2000
End If
```

Comment: you should always take extra care when dealing with `WorksheetFunction` object in VBA. whenever you use this and there is possibility of returning an error value,  always add an error handler. see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim Result As Variant
If Not VBA.IsError(Application.Match(...)) Then
    Result = Application.Match(...)
End If
```

This tries the match and if there is an error on the function it will not assign a result.

Alternatively:

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A10")
Dim Result As Variant

Result = Application.Match("A", rng, 0)
If Not VBA.IsError(Result) Then
    Debug.Print (Result)
End If
```

Note: be sure to use `Application.Match` rather than `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` for this to work.

[WorksheetFunction.Match Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx)

Comment: It returns run time error 1004 "method range of object _global failed"

Comment: Please click the check mark to the left of the answer if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this scenario, try this:

```
Dim myvalue

On Error Resume Next
myvalue = WorksheetFunction.Match("Paint Shop", Range(col & x, col & y), 0)
On Error Goto 0

If Not IsEmpty(myvalue) Then
   paint = myvalue
Else
   paint = 2000
End If
```

You incorporate `Error Handling` routine `OERN` to check if the worksheet function fails.

If it does, `myvalue` will not be initialized and you can check if it is empty or not.
Also take note that i declared `myvalue` as `Variant` data type.
Reason is for `IsEmpty` to evaluate it correctly.